# Changing Background Color for Beamer Slides

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I have the following beamer code I am using. I would like to change the background to a light cream color (we can use yellow for example purposes). I have looked on the net and here for a solution and cannot find one. (That is not to say there is not one out there.) I have cobbled together the following MWE. What I would like is for both of these slides to have a yellow background. And all subsequent slides to have a yellow background. Thanks for your help in advance. I have included the two images I use here:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}    
\usepackage{lmodern}    

\definecolor{devryblue}{RGB}{5, 51, 92}    
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=devryblue}    
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{devryblue}\bfseries\insertframetitle\par}    
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}    
%Global Background must be put in preamble    
\usebackgroundtemplate%    
{%    
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]
{/Users/gregoryegilbert/Desktop/basic_statistics/jpg/UW_DVG_Background.jpg}%        
}

\begin{document}    
% Local background must be enclosed by curly braces for grouping.    
{    
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]
{/Users/gregoryegilbert/Desktop/basic_statistics/jpg/UW_DVG_Title_Page.jpg}}    
\begin{frame}    
   \centering    
   Statistics for the Novice and Applied Researcher: Correct, Meaningful, and Clear 
Statistical Interpretation   \par    
   \vspace*{.5cm}    
   Gregory E. Gilbert, EdD, MSPH, PStat$^{\textregistered}$ \\    
   Biostatistical Research Associate \\    
   DeVry Education Group \\    
   Downers Grove, IL   \par    
   \vspace*{.5cm}    
   Katie Haerling, PhD, RN \\    
   University of Washington -- Tacoma \\    
   Tacoma, WA \\    
\end{frame}    
}    

\begin{frame}{Conflict of Interest}    
      \vspace*{-1cm}    
      Gregory E. Gilbert owns stock in DeVry Education Group (NYSE: DV).    
      \vfill    
      Katie Adamson has no conflict of interest to declare.    
    \vspace*{1cm}    
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a `jpg` as the entire background. Wouldn't it be easier to change that `jpg` in the appropriate software?

Comment: If you comment the `\includegraphics` commands you'll see that your background is indeed yellow but the images cover the canvas completely with their white area hiding the background. jpg does not support transparency so it is just better to either color the background of the images or break them down in smaller pieces (maybe even vectorial?)

Comment: Convert your jpg imagens to png setting the white color as transparent with some image editor. This should work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because comments explain this behaviour